# How to short curcit null parameter (SQL)

Tags: c#, sql

Hello Friends i have the following query which defeat the very purpose.

A day ago i asked suggestion for to sort circuit the parameter which are null for that i got the suggestion to use
`(@firstYrPercent is null OR first_year_percent>=@firstYrPercent)` like this to deny null parameter but today when i am running actual query i think that above mentioned idea is of no use.

I am getting sql exception for all those parameter which are null and it is demanding value for those error is this Sql Exception is caught:

> "Parameterized Query '(@courseId int,@passoutYear int,@currentBacklog int,@sex int,@eG' expects parameter @currentDegeePercentage, which was not supplied.   "

Here is the query please suggest me an alternative:

```
string cmd = @"SELECT * FROM [tbl_students] WHERE course_id=@courseId 
          AND  branch_id IN(" + branchId + @") 
          AND (@firstYrPercent is null OR first_year_percent>=@firstYrPercent)
          AND (@secondYrpercent is null OR second_year_percent>=@secondYrPercent)
          AND (@thirdYrPercent is null OR third_year_percent>=@thirdYrPercent)
          AND (@finalYearpercent is null OR final_year_percent>=@finalYearpercent)
          AND (@currentDegeePercentage is null OR current_degree_percent>=@currentDegeePercentage)
          AND (@passoutYear is null OR passing_year>=@passoutYear) 
          AND (@currentBacklog is null OR current_backlog<=@currentBacklog)
          AND gender=@sex 
          AND (@eGap is null OR gapin_education<=@eGap)
          AND (@highSchoolPercentge is null OR highschool_percentage>=@highSchoolPercentge)
          AND (@higherSchoolPercentage is null OR ssc_percentage>=@higherSchoolPercentage)
          AND (@grauationPercentage is null OR graduation_percentage>=@grauationPercentage)
          AND (@diplomaPercentage is null OR diploma_percentage>=@diplomaPercentage)
          AND (@noOfAtkt is null OR number_of_ATKT<=@noOfAtkt)
          AND (@date is null OR DOB>=@date)";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure you define the @currentDegeePercentage parameter on the Command you are executing - specifically, if you want to pass in that parameter as null, ensure the parameter is added to the command with a value of: `DBNull.Value`.

If you don't add the parameter to the Command.Parameters collection, or add it but set the value to null (as opposed to DBNull.Value), then you will get the error you are seeing.

Comment: first of all it's not a stored procedure and whatever demand you have made above i have done all that but still it's giving the error.
And it give the error for only those parameter which are having null value. While when i provide all parameter error is not at all. Please let me know what is the error?

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet - It doesn't have to be a stored procedure, I didn't mention sprocs. The point is, if you build ANY form of SQL statement to execute that contains parameters (whether it be a stored procedure or an adhoc SQL statement like this) - you MUST make sure you define all of those parameters on the Command being executed else you get the error you are seeing. The exception is when you do use stored procedures as then you could use default/optional parameters.
If you post your code where you are executing the SQL from .NET, that would help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not that the parameter is `null` but that the parameter is missing. Check for typos (it's "degree", not "degee" [sic]).

Comment: no i n my case it's "degee" not the degree ok.
And have already tested it for all value when i provide all the parameter with nothing null value it does work.